# webserver process permissions problems on vagrant+nginx+php fpm

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, vagrant

I have a vagrant box with a LEMP (linux, nginx, mariadb, php) stack for developing a webapp and I am currently having some issues configuring nginx and php-fpm. I am using puppet and puPHPet to provision the VM.

It seems that the combo php-fpm and nginx are unable to write files (ie. log files generated, assets published by the framework (yii2) etc).

This project worked just fine using apache instead of nginx, so I would discard a programming issue and I have been following the guidelines for nginx installation and still getting messages such as "**The directory is not writable by the Web process**" or "**Permission denied**" like errors.

As recommended I set `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` the option `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0`.

**nginx/sites-available/site.conf**

```
server {
 listen                *:80;

 server_name           site.dev;
 client_max_body_size 128M;

 root /var/www/frontend/web;
 index  index.php;

 access_log            /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
 error_log             /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;
 location / {
  root  /var/www/frontend/web;
  try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php$is_args$args;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
  root  /var/www/frontend/web;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  include fastcgi_params;
 }


 sendfile off;
}
```

**php-fpm/www.conf**

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen-owner = www-data
listen-group = www-data
listen-mode = 0660
```

I've seen other posts where listen-mode is commented out, I tried both methods and setting mode to `0666` but still no luck.

I tried also setting permissions from the out and the inside of the vagrant to `0777` over the folders that I know that the framework uses to write data but still no luck.

I have a very similar project at work configured just the same that it works but this one doesn't and I can't find the difference (in fact I took config files from this project to set up the new one after the first failed attempt).

**ps aux | grep php**

```
root      php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data  php-fpm: pool www
```

Directories in the different projects seem to have the same permissions number yet onw eorks and the other doesn't.

I'm completely clueless! Ideas are very welcomed!